# Adding colors to row in nattable based on condition

Tags: java, nattable

I have a column 'Lifecycle' in my NAT Table based on which i have to set respective color to each row. 
Adding color to row works fine. The problem is when i use the scroll bar to scroll either left or right, the color disappears. I am not aware what i am missing. Kindly help me if you have any idea of how it can be resolved

My code looks like:

IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {

```
  @Override
  public void accumulateConfigLabels(final LabelStack configLabels, final int columnPosition,
      final int rowPosition) {

    Object dataValueByPosition = PhysicalDimensionNatTable.this.bodyLayer.getDataValueByPosition(10, rowPosition);

    if ((dataValueByPosition != null) && dataValueByPosition.equals("Valid")) {
      configLabels.addLabel("VALID");
    }
    if ((dataValueByPosition != null) && dataValueByPosition.equals("Invalid")) {
      configLabels.addLabel("INVALID");
    }
    if ((dataValueByPosition != null) && dataValueByPosition.equals("Obsolete")) {
      configLabels.addLabel("OBSOLETE");
    }
  }
};
this.bodyLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
```

this.natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {

```
  @Override
  public void configureRegistry(final IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
    Style cellStyle = new Style();
    cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper.COLOR_GREEN);
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL, "VALID");

    cellStyle = new Style();
    cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper.COLOR_RED);
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
        "INVALID");

    cellStyle = new Style();
    cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper.COLOR_YELLOW);
    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
        "OBSOLETE");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is that the `IConfigLabelAccumulator` is registered on the bodyLayer, and I assume that is a stack where the top most layer is the `ViewportLayer`. `bodyLayer.getDataValueByPosition(10, rowPosition);` is returning the data value of the column position 10. And the underlying cell changes on scrolling as for example the column with index 11 becomes the column at position 10 if the first column moves out of the visible range. That is the index-position-transformation which is a basic concept in NatTable.

Either you need to perform a transformation calculation e.g. via `LayerUtil` to get the index, or operate on the `DataLayer` of the body directly instead of the bodylayer stack. Then you don't need to consider the index-position-transformation. I typically suggest to use the later.

As the index-position-transformation handling is too abstract for several people, another option is to operate on the object on the `DataLayer`. For this the `IConfigLabelAccumulator` needs to know the `IRowDataProvider` to be able to access the row object. And then register it on the `DataLayer`.

An example would look like the following snippet. Of course it should be transferred to your solution with better class separation.

```
    IRowDataProvider<PersonWithAddress> bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(data, accessor);
    DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);

    bodyDataLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {

        @Override
        public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
            PersonWithAddress person = bodyDataProvider.getRowObject(rowPosition);
            if ("Simpson".equals(person.getLastName())) {
                configLabels.addLabel("YELLOW");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did as you guided. I Operated on the datalayer instead of bodylayer stack.

DataLayer dataLayer=new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);

and the config label accumulator was set to the datalayer. In that case color is not applied to any of the row/column.

On the other hand i tried

Object dataValueByPosition = PhysicalDimensionNatTable.this.bodyLayer.getDataValueByPosition(columnPosition, rowPosition);

instead of specifying the exact column position which highlighted only the concerned column value but not the entire row.

Comment: if you want to check the value of one column for the whole row, then the approach on the DataLayer should work. Not sure why it is not working for you. Maybe you need to debug your accumulator to see why the label is not applied.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for the immediate help.

Comment: Hi Dirk. Now i have got another problem using vertical scroll bar. Suppose that 13th row is highlighted in yellow color as it satisfies the condition. When i use the vertical scroll bar to view the below rows 14th row is highlighted even though it doesn't satisfies the condition. I understand that it is because of index-position transformation. Can you please help me in handling the index position transformation and  resolve it.?

Comment: I added a simple snippet that shows how to solve your issue based on the row object using the IRowDataProvider. And setting the IConfigLabelAccumulator to the DataLayer should make the index-position-transformation not necessary.

Comment: @DirkFauth I have a nattable with some data and I want to highlight text in columns , for example if a column contains 'example' as data I want to highlight this text 'example' in that cell, is it possible to do it ? any help will be highly apricated, I added some code as answer to this question

Comment: do you want to style the cell or a specific part of text inside a cell? Styling a cell should work the way you show in your snippet (btw, your code is not an answer to the question). Styling part of some text inside a cell can be done by using a different painter.