# How to set a label to row header cell based on row object condition NatTable

Tags: java, nattable

If a user makes a change in the data I want to be able to mark an indication in the row header cell of that row.

I tried a few things but was not successful.

I know that I should set a label to the cell and then decorate the cell with the icon.

I just don't know how to set a label based on the row object to the row header cell. Please help.

```java
natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
    @Override
    public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {

        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
                new CellPainterDecorator(new ImagePainter() {
                    @Override
                    protected Image getImage(ILayerCell cell, IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                        Person obj = bodyLayerStack.getFilterList().get(cell.getRowIndex());
                        if (obj.isDirty() {
                            return dirtyImage;
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                }, CellEdgeEnum.LEFT, new TextPainter()), DisplayMode.NORMAL, DIRTY_CELL_LABEL);
    }
});
```

How do I set this "DIRTY_CELL_LABEL" label to the row header cell of a particular row (not all rows).

I don't know how to accommodate my conditions in the `CellOverrideLabelAccumulator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `IConfigLabelAccumulator` as explained in our documentation https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling or the Getting started tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html or even in some posts here on stackoverflow if you search for it, e.g. [Adding colors to row in nattable based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293631/adding-colors-to-row-in-nattable-based-on-condition)

For the lazy, here is some code that could be easily added to the NatTable examples. It works with the married property instead of a dirty property that is not available in the NatTable examples:

1. register an `IColumnLabelAccumulator` to the row header layer

   ```
   RowHeaderLayer rowHeaderLayer =
       new RowHeaderLayer(rowHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());

   rowHeaderLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {

       @Override
       public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
           Person person = bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider().getRowObject(rowPosition);
           if (person.isMarried()) {
               configLabels.addLabel("MARRIED");
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. Register the styling

   ```
   natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {

       @Override
       public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
           configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
                   new CellPainterDecorator(
                           new TextPainter(),
                           CellEdgeEnum.LEFT,
                           new ImagePainter() {
                               @Override
                               protected Image getImage(ILayerCell cell, IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                                   return image;
                               }

                           }),
                   DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                   "MARRIED");
       }
   });
   ```

Note that an additional check in the `ImagePainter` is not needed as the label is only applied to cells with that state.

Comment: I tried to do the following but that sets an icon in all cell of columns in the table (not the header cell)

Comment: IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {

    @Override
    public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {
     Person person = bodyLayerStack.getBodyDataProvider().getRowObject(rowPosition);
     if (person.isDirty()) {
      configLabels.addLabel(DIRTY_CELL_LABEL);
     }
    }
   };

Comment: You need to register it on the row header layer

Comment: I don't know how to?

Comment: The same way you do it on the body region. Or how do you do it now?

Comment: Neither the code in the question nor the code in the comment is registering the IConfigLabelAccumulator

Comment: As the provided code in the question is not showing the necessary information I have updated my answer. Hope that helps now.

Comment: Thank you. Updated answer helped.